# Render dense point cloud using XNA4.0

Tags: xna, kinect

my trying to use XNA4.0 to render a dense point cloud from Kinect. The only way I know is to render each point as a triangle primitive. It works fine for a small set of points however, the maximum number of primitive I can draw from one call is 65535, but I want to draw a dense 640*480 depth image. Any suggestion on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are targetting `Reach` profile, change your project settings to `HiDef` instead; this way you will be able to draw 1048575 primitives per call.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to draw the entire point cloud in one call?  Populate a dynamic buffer with as many points as you can fit, render it, then populate it with the next batch and render again, etc.  It's not quite as efficient as a single draw call, but 640x480 points is still only 5 batches of 65535, which is by no means excessive.

You might also want to look into hardware instancing, which will still run into the same problem, but which is more efficient for rendering large numbers of identical objects.